# Another way to get latest records based on date value

Tags: python, dataframe, hive, pyspark

I have an input date, but as example as below: df_inp

```
customer_id  |ph_num|date      |
1            |123   |2020-10-01|
2            |456   |2020-10-01|
3            |789   |2020-10-01|
1            |654   |2020-10-02|
2            |543   |2020-10-03|
1            |908   |2020-10-04|
4            |123   |2020-10-02|
```

I need to get the latest record for every daily process. So, I tried with windows rank() operation and it works. But, as the input data is coming in millions to optimize the performance can we use any other spark operations to get the latest data based on customer_id and ordering on date value.

```
window_func = Window.partition_by("customer_id ").orderBy("date")
df = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window_func))
df = df.filter(df.rank == "1")
```

Here, the customer_id - string and date - timestamp

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 3.0+ it might be worth to check if [max_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#max_by) (or [min_by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#min_by) if you take rank 1 as in the question) has better performance characteristics than the `window` + `filter` approach.

```python
df.groupBy("customer_id").agg(F.expr("max_by(ph_num,date)"), F.max(F.col("date")))
```

The result is the same as in the question. Comparing the execution plans of both approaches the `max_by` way has one transformation (the `filter`) less, but both approaches will trigger one exchange.

Comment: Thanks how can I pass groupby columns and agg max columns dynamically?? or through as variable??

Comment: @Rocky1989 the strings are just normal Python strings and can be replaced by a variable